# How to set up my iMessage account on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, messages

I've been trying to set up my iMessage account so that I can receive my texts and messages to my computer. I've set up my iCloud, and my AIM, and my FaceTime, but I can't figure out how to set up my iMessage, any help?

Answer (score 1):

This support page from Apple should help you out greatly:

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201349

This page should help you set it up on OS X (it's using OS X Mavericks to explain the instructions, but it's the same steps if you have OS X Yosemite), and will give you troubleshooting tips for if your phone number is missing on OS X.

Hope this helps.